# Google Product Search do not response with gray results

Tags: google-vision, google-product-search

I am trying the API with several products with white background and i testing those products with several images that have similar thing to those products in the image ( real life enviroment image )

I always get 0 presition. I could not get 0.2 or 0.5 or something different than 0.

Could anyone get those kind of values about match?

Comment: As a test, what do you get when you send a query image that is imported as one of the products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because i was printed the INT value and not the FLOAT one.